# Include Google Font in Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Anyone know how I can include a google fonts style sheet in my rails app? I have tried adding

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,900,200' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Into my `application.html.erb` but that doesn't do anything

Comment: add provided link between head in application.html.erb and in CSS font-family: 'Font Name', cursive;

Comment: Probably your font CSS is font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

Comment: sorry - don't get what you mean!

Comment: just to clarify - I know how to use CSS and Google Fonts normally but it's the fact that Im using Rails which is the problem

Comment: finally solved the issue and it was of course my own stupidity. It was the order of the css files that was causing the problem so over-rode the order by editing the application.css file.

Comment: @tommyd456 Please answer your own question and accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I was struggling with this one, because I had a line like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 
media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

It's hard to tell where to put your link at a first sight.

That you wanted to do is to place your stylesheet link **AFTER** `'application'`, divide it by commas. Like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application',
'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400&subset=latin',
 media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Then use it in your stylesheet as usual with *font-family* property.

Of course, we can @import it in a SASS, or do it as usual with a *link* tag, but that's just an another way and it's should be mentioned here.

Comment: You answer should be the accepted solution because this is the proper way to do it imo.

Answer (score 16):

Simply add the code provided by google to the top of your application.scss file.

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Rubik');`

please note rails will provide you with application.css file out of the box with require statements. remove these and rename application.scss

remember to add @import filename; for any other custome scssfiles in the folder

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it, the fonts don't belong in `application.html.erb`. Better yet you can just make a `fonts.scss`, importing all the fonts you need and then include it in `application.scss` so you have yourself a little font manifest

Answer (score 3):

If you add the font via @import as shown in other comments, under @import Bootstrap in application.css, the asset pipeline compiles it into the application stylesheet. If you put it in the head of your html as a link, it gets added as a separate stylesheet which slows down the page loads. You can add the @import code just as Google provides from the fonts you choose on the Google font site.

Comment: This tip is very very important! Thanks for share!

Answer (score 2):

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 <!-- Google font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
 ............
```

application.css

```
body {
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

I use it this way, maybe this will clarify.

UPDATED

Try to remove your scaffold.css.scss! Or just open and comment out all body part of CSS of this file.

Comment: Hmmm - this doesn't work for me for some reason. I have viewed source and the ref is there but no effect!

Comment: application.css is a manifest file and should not include styling.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most integrated way is to edit app/assets/views/application.html.erb and change:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran','application.css' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

## stick this inside the head section of application.html.erb

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,900,200' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

## stick this in your css file:

```
body{
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't seem very rails..? How could I re-factor this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are putting `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,900,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` this to your desire layout?

And in your respective `<layout>.css` stylesheet, did you putted `font-family:Raleway;`?

Make it sure.
Thanks.